# Using Mountebank, is it possible for an imposter to perform some logic after returning a response to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, mountebank

My app has a workflow where it calls out to an external service and receives a response. Sometime after that, the external service will eventually call an endpoint in my app. For integration testing, is it possible to setup an imposter with Mountebank to mimic this behavior?

In my research, my best guess is to use an injection and then maybe setTimeout() to later perform the POST request I need to make. However, I'm not sure that this is what Mountebank was intended to do.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Please share some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that this is stretching mountebank's functionality a bit, but there are at least three options. You identified the first, using injection and a setTimeout(). You might be able to do effectively the same thing with a decorator behavior and a setTimeout without having to build the entire response in JavaScript. The third option would be to use a shellTransform behavior, which lets you shell out to another program that could be responsible for the delayed behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the verification! I do like your idea of using a decorator instead. I'll try it and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Through lots of trial and error, I seemed to have gotten it working with a decorator and Axiom to perform the post request. It's not pretty, but I think it'll do. Thanks again!